# fundamentals of assembly language

Tags: assembly, assemblies, inline-assembly

```
MOV AX, SOMETHING
LINE1
LINE2 JZ LABEL1
LINE3
LABEL1:
LINE4
LABEL2:
LINE5
```

I am confused that after execution of LINE4, the control will go to LINE5 or will go to LINE3.

Answer (score 0):

```
LINE4
LABEL2:
LINE5
```

If *LINE4* doesn't contain some kind of jump instruction (conditional or not), the execution will continue (fall through) at *LINE5*.
The line that reads *LABEL2:* is not an instruction but an positional indicator for use by the assembler.

Why don't you fill in the actual instructions?

Comment: thanks fifo, thanks a lot for your help. I am quite satisfy now.